# What are the steps to setup an RTOS application on STM32 using Linux and Makefiles instead of using Windows based IDEs?

Tags: makefile, arm, embedded-linux, stm32, rtos

I am using STM32F4 Discovery board to develop a simple application to on-board accelerometer while simultaneously lighting respective LEDs mounted around the accelerometer device. I want to use any RTOS but I am unable to decide which one since I am new to using RTOS.

If anyone could elaborate the steps to start this project by using Linux and some Makefiles, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Eh? There's not really any functional difference between clicking the "Build" button in an IDE and typing "make" on a command line - either way, source code goes in and a binary image comes out. The notion of "good" is entirely subjective.

Comment: If you just want to light some leds relative to your accelerometer status, there is no need to have a RTOS. Nevertheless, I already have used [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org) on a STM32F4 discovery board and a simple Makefile (and a toolchain) with success. But as @Notlikethat said: *"this is entirely subjective"*

Comment: @Notikethat, I know that there is no functional difference. I am sorry I should have re-framed my question in this way: What are the different steps we need to take while building an RTOS using linux and using Windows. Basically, I want to know what I need to do differenly on my my part to use Linux rather than using Windows based IDEs, Thanks.

Comment: @jml, Could you please provide the steps here as to how you used makefile and what are the steps you took to port FreeRTOS on STM32F4 discovery? Appreciate it.

Comment: What are you actually asking?  You can use make on Windows and you can use an IDE on Linux - it seems like a false choice - use the OS that you are happy with, and that (more importantly) your chosen tool-chain runs on.  Most IDEs use proprietary project file formats so that switching tools may be difficult; some actually use makefiles, or can generate them.

Comment: @Clifford, I am asking for steps to build and port an RTOS using linux rather than Windows. I have used Windows baesd IDEs like Keil or IAR but I want to learn building and porting RTOS using Linux. If you could help me with this, it will be of great help.

Comment: what toolchains are you planning to use on linux that you cant use on windows?  take a gcc based one for example.  same toolchain same steps on windows or linux, what is it you think is different.  you type make or you push the build button, independent of the host operating system.

Comment: @EmbeddedManiac :  My point was that the host platform has no specific impact on the "building and porting" of an RTOS - why would it?  Any clarification you choose to offer however should be applied by editing the question not adding comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to start your project using Linux and Makefiles:

## Step 1: Get a toolchain

On Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

Or on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded):

```
wget https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.9/4.9-2015-q1-update/+download/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q1-20150306-linux.tar.bz2
tar xjf gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q1-20150306-linux.tar.bz2
```

## Step 2: Get the needed sources

### Step 2.1: The standard library

You can choose the [STM32F4 DSP and standard peripherals library](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/LN1939/PF257901)

Or, you can also use another library like [libopencm3](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3).

### Step 2.2: The RTOS

The most common is to use [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/).

## Step 3: Create the Makefile

Just do something like that:

```
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-

SRC := myapp.c
SRC += <the needed library files>
SRC += <the needed freertos files>

myapp.elf: myapp.bin
        $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy -Obinary $@ $<

myapp.bin: $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
        $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc -mthumb -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
        $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc -mthumb -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -Os -c $< -o $@
```

*You should add some `-I` or `-L` to fix the include issue.*

*The needed FreeRTOS files are: `list.c, queue.c, tasks.c, portable/MemMang/heap_4.c, portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.c`*

*There is a [example project](https://github.com/cjlano/freertos/tree/master/FreeRTOS/Demo/CORTEX_M4F_STM32F407ZG-SK) in the `Demo/CORTEX_M4F_STM32F407ZG-SK` which can help you.*

## Step 4: Build

Add your toolchain directory in the path and run your Makefile:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/toochain/bin"
make
```

## Step 5: Flash

You have to use the [DFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#DFU) mode of the STM32F4.

Install the tool on Ubuntu with `apt-get install dfu-util` then you can flash your `elf` file by using:

```
sudo dfu-util -a 0 -s 0x08000000 -D myapp.elf
```

Comment: DFU is not the only means of flashing the device.  You can use the JTAG/SWI debug interface, and that is needed in any case if you want to debug on the target.  Its a hard slog doing any significant work without debug capability.

Comment: @Clifford Yes you are right, DFU is not the only way to flash the device. Nevertheless it is the way I have used, and I known it is working on Linux and without IDE (as requested by @EmbeddedManiac). If you can add some other tips, feel free to edit my answer or create a new one.

Comment: I think your answer is fine (especially given the lack of clarity in the question), it was just the *"you have to use [...] DFU"* part that I felt need moderation.